Multiple google.visualization.events.addListener in Google Charts do not work together
I have a problem with a conflict between multiple event listeners in a Google Chart display. I have a Google Pie Chart with three event listeners, an onmuseover, an onmouseout and a ready event. The ready event allow saving the chart as a png image, while the onmouseout/onmouseover events change the background color of some divs when hovering the mouse over the chart's slices. My problem is the following: the two onmouseover/onmouseout events work when alone, the ready event also works when  alone but when all three of them are active the ready event works but the onmouseover/onmouseout do not! There is somewhere a conflict between these events and I can not figure out where. My code is below.
Also, is there a way I could sort the percentage values of the piechart slices so that the highest percentage to automatically change the background color of a div?
Thank you, Felix
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      function drawChart() {
       var SAIDFinal = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('SAID_Result'));
       var SIDDFinal = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('SIDD_Result'));
       var SIRDFinal = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('SIRD_Result'));
       var MODFinal = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('MOD_Result'));
       var MARDFinal = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('MARD_Result'));
       
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Diabet', 'Tipul'],
          ['SAID', SAIDFinal],
          ['SIDD', SIDDFinal],
          ['SIRD',  SIRDFinal],
          ['MOD', MODFinal],
          ['MARD', MARDFinal],
        ]);
        var options = {
          pieSliceText: 'none', 
          pieHole: '0.3',  
          pieStartAngle: 270,
           chartArea: {
    left: '20',
    top: '30',
    right: '20',
    bottom: '30',
    width: '500',
    height: '500',
   },
   
   pieSliceTextStyle: {
            color: 'black'
        },
        
     slices: {
        0: {color:'#ff0000' },
        1: {color:'#d7c9bc' },
        2: {color:'lightgreen'},
        3: {color:'orange'},
        4: {color:'magenta'}, 
        /*textStyle: {color:'black'},    
      },
    
    legend: { 
          position: 'labeled', 
          /*alignment: 'center' ,
          orientation: 'vertical',*/
          textStyle: { color: 'black', fontSize: '24'}    
    },
    
        };

     options.slices[data.getSortedRows([{column: 1, desc: true}])[0]].offset = 0.1;
        

   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        piechart.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
        console.log(piechart.innerHTML);
      });
    
    chart.draw(data, options);  
        
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(e) {
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'SAID') {
            document.getElementById('SAIDtype').style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
          }
          else if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'SIDD') {
            document.getElementById('SIDDtype').style.backgroundColor = '#d7c9bc';
          }
          else if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'SIRD') {
            document.getElementById('SIRDtype').style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
          }
          else if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'MOD') {
            document.getElementById('MODtype').style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
          }
          else if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'MARD') {
            document.getElementById('MARDtype').style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
          }
        });
      
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function(e) {
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'SAID') {
            document.getElementById('SAIDtype').style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'SIDD') {
            document.getElementById('SIDDtype').style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'SIRD') {
            document.getElementById('SIRDtype').style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'MOD') {
            document.getElementById('MODtype').style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
          if (data.getValue(e.row, 0) === 'MARD') {
            document.getElementById('MARDtype').style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
        });
        
        }
 


for one, all the event listeners need to be added before the chart is drawn for the first time.
